# Property of colon ideal: $I: (J+K)=(I:J)\cap(I:K)$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, monomial-ideals

> Let $I,J,K$ are ideals in a commutative ring with unity $R$ Then
>   $I:(J+K)=(I:J)\cap(I:K)$

My solution is if $a\in I: (J+K)$ then $a(j+k)\in I$. For all $j+k\in J+K$
$aj+ak\in I$ but $aj \in I$ and $ak \in I$ hence $aj \cap ak \in I$ so 
I don't know how I can prove $a$ is in another set. I want some help here.

Comment: Do you want $I:(J+K)=(I:J)\cap(I:K)$ in your title?

Comment: oh no i want proof of this .

Comment: Then please say so. You have $(I:K)\cap(I:K)$ in your text.

Comment: yes I:(J+K)=(I:J)∩(I:K) in text

Comment: @khubbaibNaeem Please, read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question . Your question is not readable now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to prove $$I:(J+K)=(I:J)\cap (I:K).$$If $a\in I:(J+K)$ then $aj+ak\in I$ for all $j\in J$ and $k\in K$ as you already noted. So taking $k=0$ in particular, we can say that $aj\in I$ for all $j\in J$ and taking $j=0$, we can say $ak\in I$ for all $k\in K$ that is, $a\in (I:J))$ and $a\in (I:K)$.

Comment: and if we take a∈(I:J)∩(I:K) then a∈I:J and a∈I:K so aj∈I for all j∈J and ak∈I for all k∈K so aj+ak∈I hence a(j+k)∈I Implies a∈I:(J+K) IS this is true ??

Comment: @khubbaibNaeem https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: ok thanks Ramil i shall be careful in future .i m posting first time

Comment: yes $aj+ak\in I$ for all $j\in J$ and $k\in K$ and so $a(j+k)\in I$ for all $j\in J$, $k\in K\Rightarrow a\in I:(J+K)$

Comment: @pjk if j=0 then ok but if j not zero then ?

Comment: It is true for all $j\in J$ so wouldn't it be true for a particular value of $j$, namely $0$? And it is guaranteed that $0\in J$.